# Error when trying to pass the returned value to the provider block using the null resource & local_file data block

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am seeing the following error:

> Failed to parse host: parse "https://"https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xx.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com"\n": net/url: invalid control character in URL, while performing terraform apply

All I was trying to do is to use a null resource, to execute eks command, and output it to a txt file and using data "local_file", tried passing the returned value to host argument to the provider block below

```
resource "null_resource" "endpoint" {
  //Trigger everytime
  triggers = {
    build_number = timestamp()
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws eks describe-cluster --name ${var.cluster_name} --query cluster.endpoint >> ${path.module}/output.txt"
  }

}
```

```
data "local_file" "output" {
  filename   = "${path.module}/outputtxt"
  depends_on = ["null_resource.cluster_endpoint"]
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.local_file.output.content
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.local_file.output.certificate)
  exec {
    command     = "aws"
    args        = ["eks", "get-token", "--cluster-name", ${var.cluster_name}]
  }
}
```

How can I make sure, to pass the cluster endpoint to the provider block using the null resource & local_file data block?

Comment: You probably want to do that in a different way. There are data sources for EKS, which would make your life easier.

Comment: Can you add the `cluster_name` variable and its value to the question, omitting the part the would identify the cluster in entirety?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$var.cluster_name
```

it should be

```
"${var.cluster_name}"
```

or just

```
var.cluster_name
```

Comment: I edited the description, I copied it incorrectly.